# Normalize/canonicalize XSD schema schema for text comparison

Tags: xml, xsd, comparison, normalization

I have 2 versions of an XSD file and I want to see what changes were made between them. Unfortunately, the publishers have chosen to completely rewrite the XSD, changing around the order of elements, attributes, namespace prefixes, etc. Is there a tool (either command line or GUI) that would transform both of them into a normalized form that I can then compare as text (eg. in Beyond Compare)?

Answer (score 2):

[QTAssistant](http://www.paschidev.com) (I am associated with it) has the ability to either convert an XSD file to follow the structure of another XSD file (referred to as "template"), or to convert an XSD to a "normal" form (proprietary, simply because we're not aware of any standard format).

This functionality is available as part of an XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) project, which is really a way to collect metadata about XSD files, and define how the model (defined using the schema language) might be transformed into another model, which could be expressed using XSD, or JSON schema, etc.

You could also do without any conversion, since QTAssistant supports [XSD-aware compare](https://www.paschidev.com/whitepapers/comparing-xsd-files.aspx) right out of the box; this type of compare is much more powerful, in my opinion, than any type of text compare.